# Cookie free domain - not working

Tags: cookies, cdn

I have setup a cookie free domain for use with a CDN. I have run YSlow and it is saying that I should use a cookie free domain. I have checked all the cookies and I can't see any that could be passed to the cookie free domain. Is there a way to find out the offending cookie and get a definitive answer?

If you want to take a look, the website is: [MyTechBlog](http://mytechblog.com)

The cookie free domain is: whealmedia.com

Comment: YSlow is broken on my Firefox, so I can't run it. But I checked your website, and I don't see any cookie created by whealmedia.com.

Comment: @MathieuImbert Thanks, that's what I thought. Maybe YSlow is just incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what Yslow says here is that you are using resources from other domains, which are not Cookie Free.

For example:

```
http://stats.wordpress.com/e-201232.js

http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js
```

and etc...

Yslow will provide full report.

GL.